# Why can't I get a DataFrame using a generator. The entry is the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, generator

Tell me why this happens

```
trans = transform_xml(eroot)
print(next(trans))
print(next(trans))
print(next(trans))
print(type(trans))
tr_df = pd.DataFrame(list(trans))

print(tr_df)
```

In DataFrame the same values, why is this happening?

Output

```
{'MANUFACTURER': 'Azzaro', 'NAME': 'Azzaro Visit for Men EDT 100 ml M', 'EAN': '3351500011568', 'id': '34', 'SIZE': '100.0000 ml'}
{'MANUFACTURER': 'Carolina Herrera', 'NAME': 'Carolina Herrera 212 Men EDT 100 ml M', 'EAN': '8411061853160', 'id': '99', 'SIZE': '100.0000 ml'}
{'MANUFACTURER': 'Carolina Herrera', 'NAME': 'Carolina Herrera Chic for Men EDT 100 ml M', 'EAN': '8411061954966', 'id': '108', 'SIZE': '100.0000 ml'}
<class 'generator'>
     MANUFACTURER                                               NAME            EAN      id        SIZE
0           Kenzo  Kenzo L'Eau Par Kenzo pour Femme EDT tester 30...  9999901373317  137331  30.0000 ml
1           Kenzo  Kenzo L'Eau Par Kenzo pour Femme EDT tester 30...  9999901373317  137331  30.0000 ml
2           Kenzo  Kenzo L'Eau Par Kenzo pour Femme EDT tester 30...  9999901373317  137331  30.0000 ml
...           ...                                             ...            ...     ...         ...
 137331  30.0000 ml
7058        Kenzo  Kenzo L'Eau Par Kenzo pour Femme EDT tester 30...  9999901373317  137331  30.0000 ml
```

Comment: Start again from the beginning but remove the print lines, you probably exhausted your generator before trying to make the DataFrame

Comment: in the generator 7060 records.
i can delete next(trans) but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

You can get a dataframe, and you are getting one in your example.

Try this:

```
trans = transform_xml(eroot)
print(next(trans))
print(next(trans))
print(next(trans))
print(type(trans))
tr_df = pd.DataFrame(list(trans))
print("-"*50,"\n"*3)
print(tr_df)
```

Comment: The conclusion is the same

Comment: @Айдын  it didnt print a line like this?  `-----------------------------------------`

Comment: да он печатал -----------------------------------------

Comment: @Айдын   So everything underneath is your dataframe.....

Comment: But why is print(tr_df) all data the same? because if I print

for i in trans:
    pprint(i)


then i is different data.

P.S before writing to the dataframe, I then delete the cycle

Comment: I don't know what `eroot` is and I don't know how `transform_xml` works.  So I am not sure why the data is all the same.  You should ask that in a seperate question, but make sure you include the a sample of what `eroot` is and the source for the `transform_xml` function or library you are using